# Cannot Convert Byte to Image Windows Phone

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, windows-phone-7, wcf-data-services, vb.net-2010

Assalamu'alaikum. Hi, guys i have a problem when i convert image byte data type to image on PictureBox in Windows Phone. It says "InvalidCastExpection was unhandled".

This is code behind :

```
Namespace WP7_ClientApp
    Public Class ImageConverter
        Implements IValueConverter
        Public Function ubah(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
            Dim memStream As New MemoryStream(CType(value, Byte()))
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Dim gambar As New BitmapImage()
            gambar.SetSource(memStream)
            Return gambar
        End Function

        Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then this is XAML code :

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="daftar" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="599" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Margin="12,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image Height="100" Source="{Binding gambar,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="Image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding id}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding namaproduk}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding hargaproduk}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding keterangan}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                   </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox> 
        </Grid>
```

And then this is error screenshot : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qWB7oKLVE-s/UfpE0jhnhsI/AAAAAAAABuo/2eNvw2AmTEk/s1600/Capture.PNG

Anyone can solve this? I would be very happy, thank you.

*Note : The gambar data type is Image which is has a byte data type, my table : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2ZMzi32TXsg/UfpJ5RqRG6I/AAAAAAAABu4/qe81rZm1pq0/s320/Capture.PNG

Comment: It simply means your property `gambar` isn't a byte array

Comment: Based on your screenshot, the problem is likely to be with `CType(value, Byte())`. Might be worth checking that `value` is definitely a byte array and that `CType` is valid for the conversion.

Comment: @KooKiz & Martin Parkin : Thanks for your reply, the data type gambar is "Image" which it has a byte data type, what is wrong? This is my table screenshot : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2ZMzi32TXsg/UfpJ5RqRG6I/AAAAAAAABu4/qe81rZm1pq0/s320/Capture.PNG

Comment: Look at the type of your object, not the type of the column in the database. When the exception is thrown, hover your mouse on "value".

Comment: @KooKiz : Did you mean this? http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pdgo6iXrYCA/UfpLzlRU1kI/AAAAAAAABvI/S9TH-O9LnRw/s1600/Capture.PNG

Comment: @AnggaLisdiyanto Yes. You can see on the capture that your object is of type `Binary` (not sure what it is), and therefore isn't byte array. Instead of binding your control to `gambar`, bind to `gambar.Bytes`

Comment: @MartinParkin : If it just Byte without a CType, it become error.

Comment: @KooKiz : Alhamdulillah, it is solved. Thank you very much. I need to change the image source to Binding gambar.Bytes

Comment: By the way, how to make a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is of type Binary while your converter is expecting a byte array. Instead of binding your control to `gambar`, bind to `gambar.Bytes`.